# SQL - how to get as a query result both a column and the sum of that column's values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complicated stored procedure that calculates a column with numeric values and returns it as a part of data-set containing other columns as well. I  am trying to find a way to return in the same query the SUM of that special column as well. I use SQL Management Studio and was thinking to use an OUT parameter or even a RETURN value. But if there is a more SQL-ish way to do it will definitely prefer it.

```
SELECT  
    OrID, QN, PRID, PCKID, Person, Price, CSID,
    CASE 
       WHEN (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OrID)) > 1   
          THEN Price * 0.2   
          ELSE Price * 0.1   
    END AS Commission 
FROM   
    ( < my subquery > )
```

I would also like to add `SUM(Commission)` to the the results of the above statement.

If my data is (partial)

```
OrID|Price
----+-----
 1  | 100 
 2  | 100 
 2  | 50 
 3  | 80
```

I will get the following result

```
OrID|Price|Commission
----+-----+----------
 1  | 100 |  10
 2  | 100 |  20
 2  | 50  |  10
 3  | 80  |   8
```

And somewhere I would also like to see the SUM of the last column - 48
Something like Excel's `SUM` function at the end of the `Commission` column

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the with Rollup command. It does what you want
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT s.*, SUM(Commission) OVER (PARTITION BY OrId) as sum_commission
FROM (SELECT OrID, QN, PRID, PCKID, Person, Price, CSID
             (CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OrID)) > 1
                   THEN Price*0.2
                   ELSE Price*0.1
              END) AS Commission
      FROM (< my subquery >
           ) s
     ) s;
```

I assume you want it by `OrId`.  If not remove the `partition by`.

Comment: Now, for each column of the s.* it gives me the  "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.". Tried to add GROUP BY for the first column of the sub-query and got the error on the next and so on. Going to read about the error a little. Does someone have a good link to read ?

Comment: @LouisShraga . . . I had a typo  in the query.  It is surprising that it would generate that error, though.

Comment: I changed my query in the correct way at the first place. The error is probably not related. Tried to play with much simpler queries and each time the outer query tries to fetch a column from the inner query - I get this error. Fetching only the SUM(Commission) in the outer query works ok but then, of course, I only get one column in output and I want to have it as a report with all the data. Adding all of the inner query columns in the GROUP BY statement makes all of this completely useless as it only shows in the new column the SUM of the Commission .. on the same record only

Comment: @LouisShraga . . . You are missing the `OVER . . . `.

Comment: Right! Adding the OVER as in the answer removed the need of GROUP BY but the overall query is giving the wrong result as it only gives the sum of Commission per OrID and I am looking for a way to get a total of all Commission regardless of the OrID. Something like SUM function at the bottom of an Excel column

Comment: @LouisShraga . . . As I explain in the answer, remove the `partition by OrId`.